# npm downloads per user

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any way to find out quickly how many downloads per day for all modules attached to my account?

For example, I've published 8 modules and want to know the total downloads for all 8 without having to count them individually on my calculator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [npm-stat](https://npm-stat.com/charts.html?package=loopback-connector-mongodb&from=2017-10-01&to=2017-10-30)

It will show total downloads within a date range. Also graphs showing the number of downloads per day.

[image]

[image]